# Отправка файла в запросе python

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, requests, base64

Нужно отправить файл по api, не могу справиться с кодировкой. Файл формата pdf нужно кодировать base64 и отправить в пост запросе. 
Если я правильно понимаю, то необходимо открыть файл, прочитать, кодировать и отправить. Но что-то идет не так - файл приходит на сервер, там виден в нужном формате, но открыть не могу - битый. Значит в кодировкой косяк.

```
url = 'http://...'
headers = {
    'X-Api-Key': '.....',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
with open('s.pdf', 'rb') as file:
    f = f'data:application/pdf;base64,{base64.b64encode(file.read()).decode()}'
payload = json.dumps({"name": "s.pdf", "contents": f})
r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
```

Ответ 200. Но файл не читаемый. Не могу разобраться, что случается с кодировкой и что необходимо сделать. Возможно из-за того, что читаю файл в байтах, а нужно в строку.

Comment: А если так: `r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json={"name": "s.pdf", "contents": f})`? А точно нужно в `contents` передать `data:application/pdf;base64,`, мб нужно просто содержимое как `base64` положить?

Comment: не помогло. и наличие/отсутствие "data:application/pdf;base64," никак не влияет(

Comment: Включите логирование запросов и смотрите что не так: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/6a5662fb61f950e8596d38207df1c2c5371676ef/requests__examples/debug_logging__requests.py#L10 Добавьте в вопрос ссылку на api с описанием того запроса. Мб есть пример для другого языка или для curl. В текущем виде не знаю, что еще можно предложить -- нужно больше информации

Comment: в документации ничего нет, есть только тема на форуме. но пример пхп кода тоже дает ошибку. https://forum.espocrm.com/forum/developer-help/25990-espocrm-api-attachment-empty-response